# Codeigniter - setting session storage files multiple directories created at root

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have an issue with latest codeigniter release v3

In fact, I set the following configuration in config file to store my session files

```
// La valeur TRUE permet d'utiliser la base de données
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE; 
$config['sess_driver'] = '**files**';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . '_doc/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

It creates as asked files in ***FCPATH.'/_doc/sessions'*** dir but with a border effect which is that many directories as created each time a user proceeds to a new request :

**Example** : user executes [http//mywebsite.com/mycontroller/mymethod](http://http//mywebsite.com/mycontroller/mymethod)

**Consequence** : At the root of my server a new directory is created "mycontroller+mymethod" which contains several '*ci_session12345678etc...*' files

I let you imagine, for each query, another directory is created... root path contains many directories after few minutes, and well it's quite a mess :)

Is anyone heard about this issue ? Is it only a config issue?